# RecyclerView Overriden methods not called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this horizontal recyclerview inside a tab layout.

Things I am sure of:
1. The list is not empty and is passed correctly.
2. The adapter constructor method is called.
3. The fragment is called.

The adapter code:

```
public class ProjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectAdapter.ProjectViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<ProjectModel> project;

    public ProjectAdapter(ArrayList<ProjectModel> project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    public static class ProjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title, desc;

        public ProjectViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proj_element_title);
            desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proj_element_desc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ProjectViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.projects_element, parent, false);
        return new ProjectViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProjectViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //holder.imageView.setImageResource(projectModel.getImg_res());
        holder.title.setText(project.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(project.get(position).getDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return project.size();
    }
}
```

I added debugging points at

```
holder.title.setText(project.get(position).getTitle());
holder.desc.setText(project.get(position).getDesc());

return project.size();
```

but they were never called.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you setting the adapter? See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)).

Comment: @Cheticamp Yes of course.